# Record and show video JMF

Tags: java, jmf

I want record a video from a web camera and see what I am recording on the screen.
Individually, I can either see it on the screen that takes web camera, or record a video, but not both. When I am recording, the jpanel is not updated. It reports no errors at all.
How do I fix this? Thank you very much. Sorry for my English.

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static boolean debugDeviceList = false;
    private static String defaultVideoDeviceName = "Microsoft WDM Image Capture";
    private static String defaultAudioDeviceName = "DirectSoundCapture";
    private static String defaultVideoFormatString = "size=640x480, encoding=yuv, maxdatalength=614400";
    private static String defaultAudioFormatString = "linear, 48000.0 hz, 16-bit, stereo, signed";
    private Timer timer = new Timer(40, this);
    private Player player;

    public NewJFrame(){
        initComponents();


        MediaLocator videoMediaLocator = new MediaLocator("vfw://0");
        DataSource myDataSource = Manager.createDataSource(videoMediaLocator);

        player = Manager.createPlayer(myDataSource);
        player.start();                                    

        DataSource videoDataSource = myDataSource;
        MediaLocator audioMediaLocator = new MediaLocator("dsound://");
        DataSource audioDataSource = null;

        audioDataSource = Manager.createDataSource(audioMediaLocator);

        DataSource dArray[] = new DataSource[2];
        dArray[0] = videoDataSource;
        dArray[1] = audioDataSource;
        DataSource mixedDataSource = null;

        mixedDataSource = Manager.createMergingDataSource(dArray);


        FileTypeDescriptor outputType = new FileTypeDescriptor(FileTypeDescriptor.MSVIDEO);

        Format outputFormat[] = new Format[2];
        outputFormat[0] = new VideoFormat(VideoFormat.INDEO50);
        outputFormat[1] = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.GSM_MS);

        processorModel = new ProcessorModel(mixedDataSource, outputFormat, outputType);

        processor = Manager.createRealizedProcessor(processorModel);

        source = processor.getDataOutput();

        dest = new MediaLocator("file:.\\testcam.avi");

        dataSink = null;
        dataSinkListener = null;
        dataSink = Manager.createDataSink(source, dest);
        dataSinkListener = new MyDataSinkListener();
        dataSink.addDataSinkListener(dataSinkListener);
        dataSink.open();
    }                     

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        timer.start();
        dataSink.start();
        processor.start();
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        timer.stop();
        processor.stop();
        processor.close();

        dataSinkListener.waitEndOfStream(10);
        dataSink.close();

        Stdout.log("[all done]");
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                    new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


    public BufferedImage grabFrameImage() {
        Image image = null;
        FrameGrabbingControl fGrabbingControl = null;
        if (player != null) {
            fGrabbingControl = (FrameGrabbingControl) player.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");
        }
        javax.media.Buffer buffer = fGrabbingControl.grabFrame();
        if (buffer != null) {
            image = new BufferToImage((VideoFormat) buffer.getFormat()).createImage(buffer);
        }
        if (image != null) {
            return (BufferedImage) image;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: when I write player.start();  before processor = Manager.createRealizedProcessor(processorModel); video record, but jPanel not repaint, it white all time.
when I write player.start(); after processor = Manager.createRealizedProcessor(processorModel); I see what record web camera(jPanel repait), but when I open avi file, it's empty.
Plese help me anybody. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the jmapps jmstudio source code, good code for that in there. It's about the data sink and the filetype descriptor.

Concept: record from source via capture device, you need a data sink there and then load the system, store to a file and load a player from the file.

If you don't read from the file in the Player it doesn't work in JMF. Been online for 14.5 years and no problems with JMF live video.